# Show that $\frac{1}{2}\le \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n+k}\le1$

Tags: inequality, summation, means, harmonic-numbers

for $n\in \mathbb N^+$

$$\frac{1}{2n}\le \frac{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}}{n}\le\frac{1}{n}$$

I tried math induction and I tried take integral but I want to solve this with most elementary methods  please give me hint or just show that. Thanks....

Comment: could you show what/how you tried?

Comment: that true for n=1 and n=2 .... , if  true for n=k , for n=k+1 should be true,before this I did simplificition for from all sides "n"..

Then I couldn't calculate "$\sum_{k=0}^n1/(n+k)$"  therefore I couldnot prove "should be true for n=k+1"......

Comment: The inequality is false as stated. You can fix it by starting the summation at $k=1$.

Comment: As stated the inequality only holds for $n\geq 3$

Comment: You are simply taking arithmetical mean of several elements, the largest of them is $\frac1n$ and the smallest one is $\frac1{2n}$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak No, there are $n+1$ terms, not $n$ (but my guess is that the OP simply miscopied their homework, starting their sums at $\frac1n$ instead of $\frac1{n+1}$). (As user grand_chat already suggested.)

Comment: @Did Thanks for letting me know, I completely missed that. It seems that [at least one of the answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1912461) read the question in the same way. We will see whether the OP will confirm grand_chat's and your suggestion.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes (two answers, actually). OPs who stay silent instead of answering queries about their question, are annoying.

Answer (score 10):

It holds when **$k=1$**
$$\frac { 1 }{ n+1 } +\frac { 1 }{ n+2 } +...+\frac { 1 }{ 2n } \ge \overset { n }{ \overbrace { \frac { 1 }{ 2n } +\frac { 1 }{ 2n } +...\frac { 1 }{ 2n }  }  } =n\frac { 1 }{ 2n } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \\ \\ \frac { 1 }{ n+1 } +\frac { 1 }{ n+2 } +...+\frac { 1 }{ 2n } \le \overset { n }{ \overbrace { \frac { 1 }{ n+1 } +\frac { 1 }{ n+1 } +...+\frac { 1 }{ n+1 }  }  } =\frac { n }{ n+1 } \le 1\\ $$

Comment: it's not hint it's answer :) thanks very much....

Comment: you're welcome)

Comment: As written, this is incorrect. There are $n+1$ terms in the sum, not $n$. But I think it can be corrected.

Comment: thanks for observation @MPW

Comment: Nope, still wrong. The sums are $\frac12(1+\frac1n)$ and  $1+\frac1n$. So there is still some small work to be done to make the proper conclusion.

Comment: @MPW The inequality holds if the sum starts at $k=1$, but the inequality is wrong if it starts at $k=0$ (If $n=1$, the incorrect inequality would assert $\frac12\le \frac11 +\frac12\le 1$).

Comment: @grand_chat,i agree with you,i think it should be $k=1$

Comment: @grand_chat: Yes, I wondered if OP had stated it incorrectly. Will remove my downvote for this answer. So there really are $n$ terms in the end.

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The sum must be up to $\ds{\pars{n - 1}}$ with $\pars{n \geq 1}$:

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{rcccl}
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over n + n}} & \ds{<} &
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + n}} & \ds{<} &
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over 0 + n}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\half} & \ds{<} &
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + n}} & \ds{<} &
\ds{1}
\\[2mm]
\ds{1 \over 2n} & \ds{<} &
\ds{{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + n}} & \ds{<} &
\ds{1 \over n}
\end{array}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it is simple for you, but is a way. Using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we get $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}+\int_{0}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor +1}{\left(n+t\right)^{2}}dt
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}+\int_{0}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{\left(n+t\right)^{2}}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function and since $t-1\leq\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \leq t
 $ we get $$\frac{1}{2n}+\log\left(2\right)\leq S\leq\frac{1}{n}+\log\left(2\right)
 $$ hence the claim if $n\geq3$.

Comment: It is in any case a very nice solution! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

> We show the inequality chain 
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2}\leq\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+n}\leq 1\qquad\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> is *not valid* for $n=1,2$ and valid for $n\geq 3$.

We denote the sum with $A(n):=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+n}$.

> **Case $n=1,2,3$ :**
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(1)&=\sum_{k=0}^1\frac{1}{k+1}=1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}>1\\
> A(2)&=\sum_{k=0}^2\frac{1}{k+2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{13}{12}>1\\
> A(3)&=\sum_{k=0}^3\frac{1}{k+3}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{19}{20}<1\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We observe $A(1)$ and $A(2)$ are greater than $1$, while $\frac{1}{2}\leq A(3)\leq 1$.
>
> **Conclusion:**
>
> - The inequality chain (1) is not valid for $n=1,2$.
> - Since $\frac{1}{2}\leq A(3)=\frac{19}{20}\leq 1$ the inequality chain (1) is valid for $n=3$.

$$ $$

> **Monotonicity of $A(n)$:**
>
> We want to compare $A(n)$ with $A(n+1)$. We obtain for $n\geq 1$
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(n+1)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k+n+1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n+2}\frac{1}{n+k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n}\\
> &=A(n)+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n}
> \end{align*}
>
> When we consider with some help of Wolfram Alpha the function
>   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2x+1}+\frac{1}{2x+2}-\frac{1}{x}$$
>   with $x$ real, we see there is just one zero at $x=-\frac{2}{3}$. Since $f(1)=-\frac{5}{12}$, the function is  *negative* for $x\geq 1$ and so
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(n+1)-A(n)=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n}<0\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
> \end{align*}
>
> **Conclusion:**
>
> - $A(n)$ is monotonically *decreasing* with  increasing $n$.
> - Since $A(3)\leq 1$ we see that $1$ is an upper limit of $A(n)$ for $n\geq 3$.

Finally we  show  $\frac{1}{2}$ is a *lower limit* of $A(n)$.

> **Harmonic numbers $H_n$:**
>
> Note that $A(n)$ is closely related with *[harmonic numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)* $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> A(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}=H_{2n}-H_{n-1}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
> \end{align*}
>
> The harmonic numbers are asymptotically equal to
>   \begin{align*}
> H_n\sim \ln n+\gamma
> \end{align*}
>   with $\gamma$ the *[Euler constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)*. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A(n)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(H_{2n}-H_{n-1}\right)\\
> &\sim
> \ln(2n)+\gamma-\ln(n-1)-\gamma\\
> &\sim\ln 2
> \end{align*}
>
> **Conclusion:**
>
> - Since $\ln 2\doteq 0.69314>\frac{1}{2}$ we see $A(n)\geq\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq 3$.

$$ $$

> **Summary:**
>
> - The inequality chain (1) is not valid for $n=1,2$ and valid for all $n\geq 3$.
> - The sum is monotonically decreasing with increasing $n$.
>     $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+n}\searrow$$
> - The limit of the sum is  $\ln 2$.
>
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+n}=\ln 2$$

Comment: wow thank you very much for interesting.

Comment: @Kamikaze: You're welcome! I've updated the summary to better see the additional information of this approach.